# @ManyToOne(optional=true/false) not picked by schema auto-update

Tags: java, hibernate

I have DB with column marked as:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
MyObject field;
```

When I check the created DB schema it is correctly created as:

```
FIELD BIGINT NOT NULL
```

Now I would like to make the reference non-mandatory and I would like to do it in a way I won't need to touch the schema myself. I would like the *hbm2ddl schema update* process to take care about it.

I think it is easy in situation like `@Column(nullable=true/false)` but it seems the change in `@ManyToOne(optional=true/false)` will not be picked up by the schema update since it is runtime instruction.

Any idea how to make the change?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Thought adding @JoinColumn(nullable = true) could help but it didn't. Question is still on.

Answer (score 0):

As i know you can not change it. You must set ManyToOne optional true and then @Columns(nullable = false ) .

Comment: If you mean @Column annotation and nulable = true because that is what I am trying to achieve then it is worth noticing \@Column cannot be used together with \@ManyToOne